# Find files based on directory prefix name and copy to directory

Tags: shell-script, debian

**Question:**

Can someone please show the simplest way to do this in a shell script.

I have the following list containing directory names:

```
head -3 list.txt

271_Lsasrv_dll_MS04-011
350_Util_Manager_MS04-019
351_POSIX_MS04-020
```

For each entry in the list.txt `cd` into existing directory:

```
cd 271_Lsasrv_dll_MS04-011/
```

Take the prefix number and search in `/usr/share/exploitdb/` path

```
find /usr/share/exploitdb/ -name  271.*
/usr/share/exploitdb/platforms/windows/local/271.c
```

Copy the file to existing directory

```
cp /usr/share/exploitdb/platforms/windows/local/271.c .
```

Move back to parent directory:

```
cd ..
```

**OS info:**

```
uname -a
(Debian 4.6.4-1kali1)
```

**What have i tried?**

I found it simple enough to create the directories...

```
for fldr in $(cat list.txt); do mkdir -p $fldr; done
```

...but unsure of the best way to use cut and assign to variables etc.  It would be great to learn experienced Linux users approach this.

Comment: the prefix is always 3 numbers ?

Comment: @mazs no it could be more or less but always a number

Comment: ok but then there is always an `_`  after the prefix ?

Comment: @mazs yes correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and if it needs refinement, let me know :

```
while read line; 
do
  mkdir -p "${line}"
  prefix=`echo "${line}" | cut -d'_' -f1`
  find /usr/share/exploitdb/ -name  "${prefix}".* -exec echo {} "${line}/" \;
done < list.txt
```

Replace the `echo` with `cp` from the `find` if the command output seems ok to you.

Comment: Instead of using the `prefix` variable you could leave away the fourth line and directly use `${line%%_*}` to remove everything after the `_`, at least in `zsh` and `bash`.

Comment: nice catch @Philippos, thx. gota get used to the bash string slicing

Comment: @mazs This is actually not just `bash`, but should work in every POSIX compliant shell, see [chapter parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02)

Answer (score 1):

```
< list.txt xargs -r sh -fc '
   mkdir -p "$@"
   cmd="find /usr/share/exploitdb -name ${1%%_*}.* -exec cp -vt $1/. {} +"; shift
   for d; do cmd="${cmd} -o -name ${d%%_*}.* -exec cp -vt $d/. {} +"; done
   $cmd
' sh
```

Working:

- The starting point is the `list.txt` file which is funneled into `xargs` which in turn hands them over to `sh` in a slurp-mode on it's argument list.
- Next the directories are created if not already present.
- Now we `dynamically` build the `find` command based on the data passed to us in a manner that all the common-named files are pulled at once and then `cp` at once to the appropriate directory. This helps in keeping the invocations of `find` to the barest minimum. For example, here is what the `find` command would look like for the data set shown by the `OP`:

  `find /usr/shar/exploitdb -name 271.* -exec cp -vt 271_Lsasrv_dll_MS04-011/. {} + -o -name 350.* -exec cp -vt 350_Util_Manager_MS04-019/. {} + -o -name 351.* -exec cp -vt 351_POSIX_MS04-020/. {} +`
- Assuming the directory contains no whitespaces and shell metacharacters.